# Reading data from a bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth

I bought a Bluetooth thermometer/hydrometer device. When I run the command

```
bluetooth scan on
```

I get continuous data from the device similar to what follows

```
[CHG] Device 45:7E:48:99:24:E8 ManufacturerData Key: 0x0ec2
[CHG] Device 45:7E:48:99:24:E8 ManufacturerData Value: 01 27 02 2c
```

After some efforts I got the meaning of this data but I cannot find a way to pipe/redirect it to a file for parsing later. A simple

```
bluetooth scan on >> file.txt
```

does not show anything until I interrupt the command.
Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to watch the output of your command while it is logging into a file. `tee` command is used for this, it is sending a command's output to both a file and standard output.

`-a` stands for `--append`, to implement this `>>` redirection.

```
bluetooth scan on | tee -a file.txt
```

Or use `tail -f` to watch what is appended to file while the command is running:

```
bluetooth scan on >> file.txt &
tail -f file.txt
```